# How to host a Gatsby+Node.js project on a shared hosting?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hosting, gatsby, shared-hosting

I have a project in `gatsby` which uses `Node.js/express` for backend with `MySQL`.

Now, I know that all I have to do is `gatsby build` and that will create the static `html/css/js` files for me in the `project/public` folder and I can paste all of them in `public_html` folder and that will work(it is working), but Im confused about the database thing:

My issue is that in the `gatsby-config.js` when I change the mySql connection from `localhost` to the `hosted db` settings such as:

[image: db config]

(The commented one is the hosted db configurations)

If I run `gatsby develop` while uncommenting the code. It says `No such DB Error`(obviously). So How can I configure the db settings here and also in the `gatsby-node.js` file to connect the db with the project?

I know this might sound like a dumb question but please help as I'm confused about what to do next.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Okay! Spent a lot of time on this. Hope it will help others.

### Static Gatsby site

If you're trying to **host a static gatsby site on any shared hosting**. By static, I mean just plain gatsby styled pages,
You can do as the [gatsby doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/preparing-for-deployment/#generate-your-site) says:

- Run :       `gatsby build`        or         `npm run build`.

According to gatsby:

> Gatsby will perform an optimized production build for your site, generating static HTML and per-route JavaScript code bundles.

- After this : try  `npm run serve`.

According to [gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/quick-start/#serve-the-production-build-locally) :

> Gatsby starts a local HTML server for testing your built site. Remember to build your site using `gatsby build` before using this command.
> `serve` will test your build files(newly created files in `yourprojectroot/public` dir)

This will run your project(using the build files) on a test server(`localhost:9000`) to basically test your build files.

Test this `localhost:9000`, If everything is working good. You can go to your remote cPanel and **paste all your build files into the public_html folder.**

Head over to your domain and you're good to go.

### Gatsby with MySQL and Node/express

If you are trying to host your gatsby site which works a little with node and mysql as well and you are a newbie in hosting like me, Here's what you'll want to do:

Try both the points mentioned above. (**Build your static files and try serve**)

Setup your db on the remote as well with the same name dbname, username and password as your local one.

**Two extra things:**

Now, what you are going to do is to run both the node and gatsby(webpack) servers on the same port (say **8001**). So we are going to use only the node server and **serve all our gatsby files(build files) as static content to node server.**

- In your node file, add:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {  
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'public/index.html'));
});
```

As you are going to run all your gatsby pages through `index.html` the last `get('/*'...` (above) will take care of all the pages request. Change the path public according to your remote folder structure

Add the build files along with the node(server connection) file in the `public_html` folder on remote.

- Next add or change your `.htaccess` file (in the remote) to :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:8001/ [P,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8001/$1 [P,L]
```

So when you run your node file through the server's terminal, instead of `yourdomainname.com:8001` the above mentioned .htaccess will redirect it to `yourdomainame.com` only

All done.

Your `public_html` now should contain `the build files`,`a node/express conn file` and `.htaccess file`.

Now, just go to your terminal. cd into public_html and run `node yournodefilename`.
You can head over to your domain now.

Note : You can use `pm2` package to keep your node server always running.
Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/environment-variables/) to switch between configurations (locally and production). Environment files are files that store sensitive data such as API keys, tokens, etc, so they must be ignored and untracked to avoid pushing critical data to a public repository.

By default, Gatsby uses `.env.development` and `env.production` respectively for `gasby develop` and `gatsby build` commands, of course, you can override this behaviour but, assuming the default configuration, you should add the following snippet to your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

Then, you need to create a `.env.development` and `.env.production` in the root of your project with the following content:

```
DB_HOST:yourHost
DB_USER:yourUserName
DB_PASSWORD:yourPassword
DB_NAME:youDatabaseName
```

Of course, each file should have different variables if you want to switch between databases or configurations.

Add them to your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
connectionDetails:{
  host: process.env.DB_HOST
  user: process.env.DB_USER
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
  database: process.env.DB_NAME
}
```

The final step is to add, in your host, the environment file in order to make them accessible by Gatsby. S3 by Amazon allows to configure them but I guess that it's a common configuration for the hostings.

Comment: Thanks for this. But can't access `process.env.DB_USER` as it says `undefined`. Any possible reasons?

Comment: It's set in your `.env.development` or `.env.production`?

Comment: Yes, I have made two .env for production and dev each. Also, the `dotenv` is configured with this ```require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})```.

Comment: Wait... `DB_HOST:yourHost` wasn't right. changed it to `=` instead of `:` .

Comment: Question:  what changes should I make here in the node proxy:   ```proxy: {
    prefix: "/api",
    url: "http://localhost:8001",
  },```  in order to detect calls for node/express??

Comment: Also, what do you mean by this : `The final step is to add, in your host, the environment file in order to make them accessible by Gatsby`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're right,  should be `=` instead of `:`. About the proxy, depends on the listening port of your express, if it listens in the `8001` you should change the running port using: `gatsby develop -p 8001`. About uploading your `.env` files, you need to make the host Gatsby to access your environment variables in your server.

Comment: Thanks for this, but still confused. Can you mention some blogs/articles/docs on this for me? Deploying/Hosting is just new for me. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/deploying-and-hosting/

Comment: question: we can run `gatsby build` and then place the static contents into the `public_html`. Is this the only standard way to host gatsby on shared hosting? Or is there something else or some other way?

Comment: Depending on your hosting provider but, generally, I would say yes. The deployed folder must be the `/public`

Comment: But as you suggested, `.env` for the modes, `gatsby build` just states `no such db error`. Any further suggestions?